# how to disconnect a data line with a digital output using the smallest component

Tags: arduino

Hi i have two stepper motors and an Arduino Uno and i need both the spetter motors to work at the same time but the only way that can be done is if both the corresponding lines for each stepper are connected together but i dont always want them to be connected, so i need to find a way to connect and disconnect the 4 lines for each stepper, i need the components to be as small as possible and i shall use one of the two remaining digital output on my Arduino which can go High or Low to connect or disconnect the lineswith is 5v logic.

What is the best component for me to use and i assumed i would just get four of them and connect them in parallel.

Many thanks and sorry for such a simple question
from Ed.

Comment: Can you draw a circuit diagram

Comment: The best way, if you have the spare pins, is to drive both motors independently. It's trivial to drive them both identically in software for when you want them coupled.

Comment: Are you using stepper drivers or are the motor leads connected directly to the Arduino's pins?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 74HC125 type buffer driver. It has an Enable* input pin for each channel which puts the driver in high Z (disconnected) state. You can input the stepper control signal from Arduino into 2 buffer drivers and connect them with the 2 stepper motors. You can use the two remaining signals from Arduino to control the Enable* Inputs of all 8 drivers.